# thrust::unique_by_key eating up last element

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust

Please consider the below simple code:

```
thrust::device_vector<int> positions(6);
thrust::sequence(positions.begin(), positions.end());
thrust::pair<thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator, thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator > end;
//copyListOfNgramCounteachdoc contains: 0,1,1,1,1,3
end.first = copyListOfNgramCounteachdoc.begin();
end.second = positions.begin();
for(int i =0 ; i < numDocs; i++){
    end= thrust::unique_by_key(end.first, end.first + 3,end.second);
}

int length = end.first - copyListOfNgramCounteachdoc.begin() ;
cout<<"the value of end -s is: "<<length;
for(int i =0 ; i< length ; i++){
  cout<<copyListOfNgramCounteachdoc[i];
}
```

I expected the output to be 0,1,1,3 of this code; however, the output is 0,1,1. Can anyone let me know what I am missing? Note: the contents of `copyListOfNgramCounteachdoc` is 0,1,1,1,1,3 . Also the type of `copyListOfNgramCounteachdoc` is `thrust::device_vector<int>`.

EDIT:

```
end.first = storeNcCounts.begin();
    end.second = storeCompactedPositions.begin();
    int indexToWriteForIndexesarr = 0;
    for(int i =0 ; i < numDocs; i++){
        iter = end.first;
        end = thrust::unique_by_key_copy(copyListOfNgramCounteachdoc.begin() + (i*numUniqueNgrams), copyListOfNgramCounteachdoc.begin()+(i*numUniqueNgrams)+ numUniqueNgrams,positions.begin() + (i*numUniqueNgrams),end.first,end.second);
        int numElementsCopied = (end.first - iter);
        endIndex = beginIndex + numElementsCopied - 1;
        storeBeginIndexEndIndexSCNCtoRead[indexToWriteForIndexesarr++] = beginIndex;
        storeBeginIndexEndIndexSCNCtoRead[indexToWriteForIndexesarr++] = endIndex;
        beginIndex = endIndex + 1;
    }
```

Comment: `end.first + 3` must point to the element after last. I guess you should pass  `end.first + 4`

Comment: Why would there ever be 4 outputs from `unique_by_key` when it only has 3 inputs?

Comment: @talonmies: If you note, i am not performing unique_by_key on the whole array. I am performing unique by key to subsequences in the array. First,  I apply it to 0,1,1, and this should give me 0,1 as the output. Then, I apply it to 1,1,3, which should give me 1,3 as the output. Thus, I expect 4 outputs in total as the for loop will execute twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to use in this case is `thrust::unique_by_key_copy`, but read on.

The problem is that `unique_by_key` is not updating your input array unless it has to.  In the case of the first call, it can return a sequence of unique keys by just dropping the duplicate `1` -- by moving the returned iterator forward, without actually compacting the input array.

You can see what is happening if you replace your loop with this one:

```
end.first = copyListOfNgramCounteachdoc.begin();
end.second = positions.begin();
thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator iter;

for(int i =0 ; i < numDocs; i++){
  cout <<"before ";
  for(iter = end.first; iter != end.first+3; iter++) cout<<*iter;

  end = thrust::unique_by_key(end.first, end.first + 3,end.second);

  cout <<" after ";
  for(iter = copyListOfNgramCounteachdoc.begin(); iter != end.first; iter++) cout<<*iter;
  cout << endl;

  for(int i =0 ; i< 6; i++) cout<<copyListOfNgramCounteachdoc[i];
  cout << endl;
}
```

For this code I get this output:

```
before 011 after 01
011223
before 122 after 0112
011223
```

You can see that the values in `copyListofNgramCounteachdoc` are not changing. This is valid behavior.  If you had used `unique_by_key_copy` instead of `unique_by_key` then Thrust would have been forced to actually compact the values in order to guarantee uniqueness, but in this case since there are only two values in each sequence, there is no need. The docs say:

> The return value is an iterator new_last such that no two consecutive elements in the range [first, new_last) are equal. The iterators in the range [new_last, last) are all still dereferenceable, but the elements that they point to are unspecified. unique is stable, meaning that the relative order of elements that are not removed is unchanged.

If you use `unique_by_key_copy`, then Thrust will be forced to copy the unique keys and values (with obvious cost implications), and you should see the behavior you were expecting.

BTW, if you can do this in a single call to `unique_by_key` rather than doing them in a loop, I suggest that you do so.

Comment: I would love to do this in one call. But as you may observe, I have to stream compact parts of the array. I do not want to stream compact the array as a whole. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I think I explained: use multiple calls to unique_by_key_copy.  You will have to double-buffer the data to do so.

Comment: I have edited my question to use unique_by_key_copy. But that does not remove the loop still.

Comment: Also you said "If you had done a unique_by_key then Thrust would have been forced to actually compact the values in order to guarantee uniqueness," did you mean unique_by_key_copy

Comment: Typo corrected. You did not ask how to remove the loop. You asked "I expected the output to be 0,1,1,3 of this code; however, the output is 0,1,1. Can anyone let me know what I am missing?" I believe I have answered the question of why the output was not what you expected.

Comment: I will be obliged if you could please give me some idea on how to remove the loop. I just timed the code and it is performing slow

Comment: Without knowing more about what you are trying to compute at a high level, I don't see a way to remove it.  You seem to need to compute the unique elements in each group of 3, dependent on previous groups.  If there is indeed that dependency on previous groups, it may not be possible to remove the loop.  Thanks for accepting.

Comment: There is no dependency on previous groups. Each group is independent of each other .Moreover, the group size is arbitrary but it is the same for all groups. does that help?

Comment: Your original example has a dependency between groups because you ran unique_by_key on the results of the previous unique_by_key.  If there is no dependency then that example did not reflect your real computation.

Comment: I think I see what you want: you want a segmented unique by key. I'm afraid Thrust doesn't provide such a beast. You will need to do it in a loop, or write a custom algorithm.